# C# assigning a drop down list value to a session value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a drop down list which retrieves values from a session I declare as follows.

```
var autoData = autoRetriever.GetAutoDataByUserId(user.Id);

            Session["AutoData"] = autoData;
```

I then use autoData to populate my drop down list with a “Name” and a int “Value” as indexed in the database. Name and value are both part of my table in the database.

What I am trying to do now is once a user selects from the drop down I am passing the value (e.g 0,1,2,3,n) the id on the db table to a method. OnSelected changed I want to use this value and retrieve another column “Path” from my session (autoData). Namely the path that is associated with the id. Once I have the correct “Path” associated with this value I can move forward with it.

With my OnSelectedIndexChanged method I then have the following. This string selectedAuto contains my value (0,1,2,3,n)

```
string selectedAuto = AutoDropDown.SelectedValue;
```

Does anyone have any advice on how I could move forward with this? If I have not explained enough please let me know and I will delve deeper into it.

As @David mentioned yes correct i am trying to use that value to identify that record. That is the part i am finding tricky. How can i retrieve that "Path" based on the value i select.

Comment: It's not really clear where you're stuck or what isn't working as designed.  `SelectedValue` is giving you the value you selected, correct?  Based on your description, that value is an identifier for a record in the data (which is exactly how a `DropDownList` is generally used).  So you can use that value to identify that record.  What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Please give the full code it is not clear

Comment: Maybe they mean they want to query the object stored in "AutoData" to find the item represented by ID?  In which case why not just bind the autoData to the drop down, then convert selectedValue into your user object.